# How to programmatically clear angular QueryList

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a writers component with following implementation

```
export class WritersComponent implements AfterContentInit {

   @ViewChildren('writer') 
   allWriters: QueryList<WriterComponent>       

   reset() {
      //want to empty querylist
      this.allWriters.reset([])
   }
```

}

I want to reset the entire querylist. I tried passing empty array allWriters method but it is not working.
FYI: I am calling the component reset method from other component using ViewChild reference to WritersComponent.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Angular official documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) querylist is An unmodifiable list of items that Angular keeps up to date when the state of the application changes.

SO you can't reset it. If you want to reset it then use something different.may an array you can use